# Can someone explain Unity co-ordinate system in 2D to me please?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D game. 
I have 4 gameobjects which i want to place in each corner of the screen., i.e when I run my app on my phone it should be visible in each corner. 
So what I did in the script is,

```c#
//GameObject 1 script
void Start(){
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
}

//GameObject 2 script
void Start(){
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));
}

//And same for other 2 gameobjects...
```

But i am not seeing any of the objects on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it in right way, but there could be some moments you should check out:

1. Make sure that you're using correct camera to translate coordinates from screen to world.]
2. Make sure that z position of your object are inside camera's clipping plane (it must be smth between camera's near clipping plane and camera's far clipping plane). You can start you game in editor and look at scene view if gameobjects are actually inside the clipping plane.
3. What you're doing is placing your gameobjects so that the *center* of each gameobject will be in the corner of the screen. And it's not like gameobject will fit the corner. If you want to place gameobject so that they will fit the corner (not their center will be placed in the corner) you should calculate the offset for each gameobject. You can user `renderer.bound` for this purpose.
4. Make sure that your camera renders the layer on which gameobjects are. You can check it in camera's culling mask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually want to place the center of the gameobject at   each corner. As an experiment i printed out this info - 
print ("SCREEN TO WORLD POINT: " + Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (0.0f, 0.0f)));

The result is (-8.5f, -5.0f, -10.0f)

How is that calculated? 
my screen resolution is (1024, 600).

Can you help?

Comment: @s3e3 what you're seeing in console is unity's coordinates. Unity doesn't deal with pixels, it deals with it's own coordinate system. (0,0) is the bottom left corner of the screen. And it doesn't deal with pixels of the screen. You can get pixel size of the screen with Camera.pixelWidth /.pixelHeight . If you want to undrestand the mapping coordinates to unity's units take a look here : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130047/how-does-the-unity-coordinate-system-map-to-screen-pixels